# Building elasticsearch indexes from another container

Tags: django, docker, elasticsearch

I have a Django project that uses [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/management.html). The project is dockerized, so elasticsearch and the web projects leave in separate containers.
Now my goal is to recreate and repopulate the indices running

```
python manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

In order to do that, I try to run the command from the container of the web service the following way:

```
docker-compose exec web /bin/bash

> python manage.py search_index --rebuild
```

Not surprsiginly, I get an error

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

apparently because python tried to connect to elasticsearch using localhost:9200.
So the question is, how do I tell the management command the host where elasticsearch lives ?

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: "no"
    command: ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    env_file: &envfile
      - .env
    environment:
      - DEBUG=True
    ports:
      - "${DJANGO_PORT}:8000"
    networks:
      - deploy_network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - db
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'elasticsearch:2.4.6'
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - deploy_network
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    container_name: "postgres"
    restart: "no"
    env_file: *envfile
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    db_data:

networks:
  deploy_network:
    driver: bridge
```

UPDATE:

In the Django project's settings I setup the elasticsearch dsl host:

```
# settings.py
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Django project and Elasticsearch are in 2 separate containers, setting ELASTICSEARCH_DSL's host to 'localhost:9200' won't work, in this case localhost refers to localhost inside Django container.

So you need to set it like this:

```
# settings.py
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'elasticsearch:9200'
    }
}
```